# How can I create an info box in HTML that shows information relevant to a hovered SVG path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an SVG with a couple paths that describe regions, like this:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        <path d="..."></path>
        <path d="..."></path>
        <path d="..."></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And I'd like to display a `div` based on which `path` is hovered. I tried putting the respective `div`s inside the paths in order to be able to do this in the css:

```
path:hover div.infobox
{
    display: block
}

div.infobox
{
    display: none
    position: absolute
}
```

But that doesn't work, because the SVG is not rendered properly if I hide non SVG elements in it.

Is there an easy way to do this by CSS or with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jQuery it should just be...

```
$("path").on("hover", function() {
    $(".infobox").toggle();
});
```

And just create the div somewhere on the page (outside of the svg) with absolute position.

If you need to do it for a specific SVG it might be better to do

```
$("#svg-id").find("path").on("hover", function() {
    $(".infobox").toggle();
});
```

Update for related path / div

SVG:

```
<path id="infobox1">...</path>
<path id="infobox2">...</path>
...
```

HTML:

```
<div class="infobox infobox1">...</div>
<div class="infobox infobox2">...</div>
...
```

Javascript:

```
$("#svg-id").find("path").on("hover", function() {
    //hide all info boxes
    $(".infobox").hide();
    //show the right one based on id - class relation
    $("."+$(this).attr('id')).show();
});
```

Comment: Problem is, I need to select the respective div, I have 20 regions and 20 divs. Is there a better way than to manually label all regions and their divs with a common class?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but you could do it by class or index.

Comment: Added example above using class / id as reference to each other.

Comment: Neat solution, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

If a simple title tooltip would do, then you can use SVG's title element (that does the same thing as an HTML title attribute):

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <path d="..."><title>text 1</tile></path>
    <path d="..."><title>text 2</tile></path>
    <path d="..."><title>text 3</tile></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You could also use SVG text:

```
<svg>
  <style type="text/css">
    text {display:none}
    svg > g > g:hover text {display:inline}
  </style>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path d="..."/>
      <text>text 1</text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="..."/>
      <text>text 2</text>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="..."/>
      <text>text 3</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You'd of course have to position the text properly and possibly add a background, either using a filter, as described in [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260370/draw-text-in-svg-but-remove-background/12263962#12263962), or a rect.