# Background color of text in SVG

Tags: css, svg, background-color

I want to color the background of svg `text` similar to `background-color` in css

I was only able to find documentation on `fill`, which colors the text itself

Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: These also might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725288/svg-text-inside-rect and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675223/background-color-of-tspan-element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260370/draw-text-in-svg-but-remove-background/12263962#12263962 also shows how to do this using filters.

Comment: @RobertLongson Closing this question as duplicate when it was asked 2 years prior to the other one seems wrong, especially when the only answer there is yours.

Comment: @Aperçu: The age of a question is not the main factor when choosing a duplicate target, see for example [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315472/2675154).

Comment: @RobertLongson would you say this question is not of comparable (if not better) quality to the other one even though it has 42 upvotes against 8? Your answer also as the same score as the lower of these two, and less than a third of the top one. The quality of your answer is rather subjective to you and shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

No this is not possible, SVG elements do not have `background-...` [presentation attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Attribute#Presentation).

To simulate this effect you could draw a rectangle behind the text attribute with `fill="green"` or something similar (filters). Using JavaScript you could do the following:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("the-svg"),
textElm = ctx.getElementById("the-text"),
SVGRect = textElm.getBBox();

var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    rect.setAttribute("x", SVGRect.x);
    rect.setAttribute("y", SVGRect.y);
    rect.setAttribute("width", SVGRect.width);
    rect.setAttribute("height", SVGRect.height);
    rect.setAttribute("fill", "yellow");
    ctx.insertBefore(rect, textElm);
```

Comment: That or use an svg filter (feFlood + feComposite) on the text. See slightly similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260370/draw-text-in-svg-but-remove-background.

Comment: This solution using getBBox(), although it works just fine, can be quite slow when a large number of calculations need to be done. The issue with using an svg filter (feFlood + feComposite) is that the text comes out a little jagged. Have offered a simple, but hacky solution below.

Comment: Better to use textElm = document.getElementById("the-text") instead of textElm = ctx.getElementById("the-text")?

Comment: How cal I use the same getBBox function in nodeJS

Answer (score 134):

You could use a filter to generate the background.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="solid">
      <feFlood flood-color="yellow" result="bg" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="bg"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <text filter="url(#solid)" x="20" y="50" font-size="50">solid background</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: What does "SourceGraphic" mean here?   Does "url(#solid)" actually cause an extra web access?

Comment: No, it shouldn’t. It’s referring to the definition of the <filter> in the <defs> tag, which is part of the svg (and hence not loaded again).

Comment: text is blurry here :(

Comment: Can yo give the background **padding**?

Comment: @vsync best aska separate question about that showing what you have so far.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I've asked, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42327183/104380)

Comment: Love this solution in theory, but can confirm that the text is blurry. It seems like the filter breaks anti-aliasing.

Comment: Me too, Love the solution, got the +1, but definitely breaks anti aliasing :(

Comment: Add `operator="xor"` to `feComposite` to prevent blurry text. @RobertLongson @teran @paulmelnikow @bill

Comment: Is is possible to make borders rounded?

Comment: Note: this doesn't work in Safari if you have a `<base href="" />` tag in your html.

Comment: x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%" to add padding

Answer (score 44):

The solution I have used is:

```html
<svg>
  <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="500" y2="100" style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 2"/>    
  <text x="150" y="105" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:0.6em">Hello World!</text>
  <text x="150" y="105" style="fill:black">Hello World!</text>  
</svg>
```

A duplicate text item is being placed, with stroke and stroke-width attributes. The stroke should match the background colour, and the stroke-width should be just big enough to create a "splodge" on which to write the actual text.

A bit of a hack and there are potential issues, but works for me!

Comment: Also prints nicely where as the filter solution was very blurry when printed.

Comment: Love it.. it looks awesome when you adjust stroke width a little.

Answer (score 27):

Instead of using a `<text>` tag, the  [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) tag can be used, which allows for XHTML content with CSS.

Comment: Can you leave an example?

Comment: Underrated answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject Contains an useful example. Within your foreignObject you can use divs & spans together with css definitions.

Comment: Doesn't work in Safari if you want to apply a CSS transformation to a DIV inside a foreignObject within an SVG.

Comment: `foreignObject` is a hack to the SVG world and not all browsers fully support it as @KernelJames mentioned.

Answer (score 18):

No, you can not add background color to SVG elements. You can do it programmatically with [d3](http://d3js.org/).

```
var text = d3.select("text");
var bbox = text.node().getBBox();
var padding = 2;
var rect = self.svg.insert("rect", "text")
    .attr("x", bbox.x - padding)
    .attr("y", bbox.y - padding)
    .attr("width", bbox.width + (padding*2))
    .attr("height", bbox.height + (padding*2))
    .style("fill", "red");
```

Comment: This does not work; it only changes the color of the text, not the background color.

Comment: Enclose the **text** in a **div** or **span** and apply styling to whichever of the last two you have used.

Comment: This post explains it well: https://cambridge-intelligence.com/customize-graph-visualization-d3-keylines/

Answer (score 12):

Going further with @dbarton_uk [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41902064/2937955), to avoid duplicating text you can use `paint-order=stroke` style:

```html
<svg>
  <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="350" y2="100" style="stroke:grey; stroke-width: 100"/>    
  <text x="150" y="105" style="stroke:white; stroke-width:0.5em; fill:black; paint-order:stroke; stroke-linejoin:round">Hello World!</text>
</svg>
```

Note the `stroke-linejoin:round` which is needed to avoid seeing spikes for the W sharp angle.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Can be added to css without changing doc itself.

Answer (score 8):

Answer by Robert Longson (@RobertLongson) with modifications:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="solid">
      <feFlood flood-color="yellow"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <text filter="url(#solid)" x="20" y="50" font-size="50"> solid background </text>
  <text x="20" y="50" font-size="50">solid background</text>
</svg>
```

and we have no bluring and no heavy "getBBox" :)
Padding is provided by white spaces in text-element with filter.
It's worked for me

Comment: Concerning padding, you'd better use the parameters `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` of `filter`. The default values provide a nice padding (I mean, not the values of your answer, but the default SVG values which are taken if you do not define them).

Comment: Using the operator `"xor"` makes the text appear as transparent instead of the chosen color (if we except the more complex case of a flood-color with alpha). Don't you want to use operator `"over"` instead?

Comment: @FlorianT then why does the text have a color? and adding `fill="red"` on the text makes the text red?

Comment: @minseong it's because the text is duplicated. What I meant is you can use only the first text element if you use operator `over` instead of `xor`

Answer (score 4):

For those wondering how to apply padding to a text element when it has a background like in the [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013492/4159337), do the following:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter x="-0.1" y="-0.1" width="1.2" height="1.2" id="solid">
      <feFlood flood-color="#171717"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <text filter="url(#solid)" x="20" y="50" font-size="50">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

In the example above, filter's **x** and **y** positions can be used as `transform: translate(-10%, -10%)` would, and **width** and **height** values can be read as `120%` and `120%`. So we made background 20% bigger, and offsetted it -10%, so background is now 10% bigger on each side of the text.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine filter with the text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>SVG colored patterns via mask</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="bg-text">
          <feFlood flood-color="white"/>
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
   <!-- something has already existed -->
    <rect fill="red" x="150" y="20" width="100" height="50" />
    <circle cx="50"  cy="50" r="50" fill="blue"/>
      
      <!-- Text render here -->
      <text filter="url(#bg-text)" fill="black" x="20" y="50" font-size="30">text with color</text>
      <text fill="black" x="20" y="50" font-size="30">text with color</text>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is my favorite hack (not sure it should work). It refer an element that is not yet displayed, and it works pretty well

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 620 40" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <defs>
        <filter x="-0.02" y="0" width="1.04" height="1.1" id="removebackground">
            <feFlood flood-color="#00ffff"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <!--Draw the text--> 
    <use xlink:href="#mygroup" filter="url(#removebackground)" />
    <g id="mygroup">
        <text id="text1" x="9" y="20" style="text-anchor:start;font-size:14px;">custom text with background</text>  
        <line x1="200" y1="18" x2="200" y2="36" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/> 
        <line x1="120" y1="27" x2="203" y2="27" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/> 
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers relied on doubling up text and lacked sufficient whitespace.

By using `atop` and `&nbsp;` I was able to get the results I wanted.

This example also includes arrows, a common use case for SVG text labels:

```html
<svg viewBox="-105 -40 210 234">
<title>Size Guide</title>
<defs>
    <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="solid">
        <feFlood flood-color="white"></feFlood>
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="atop"></feComposite>
    </filter>
    <marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto-start-reverse">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z"></path>
    </marker>
</defs>
<g id="garment">
    <path id="right-body" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M0 0 l30 0 l0 154 l-30 0"></path>
    <path id="right-sleeve" d="M30 0 l35 0 l0 120 l-35 0" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></path>
    <use id="left-body" href="#right-body" transform="scale(-1,1)"></use>
    <use id="left-sleeve" href="#right-sleeve" transform="scale(-1,1)"></use>
    <path id="collar-right-top" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M0 -6.5 l11.75 0 l6.5 6.5"></path>
    <use id="collar-left-top" href="#collar-right-top" transform="scale(-1,1)"></use>
    <path id="collar-left" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M-11.75 -6.5 l-6.5 6.5 l30 77 l6.5 -6.5 Z"></path>
    <path id="front-right" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M18.25 0 L30 0 l0 154 l-41.75 0 l0 -77 Z"></path>
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="154" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="1 3"></line>
    <use id="collar-right" href="#collar-left" transform="scale(-1,1)"></use>
</g>
<g id="dimension-labels">
    <g id="dimension-sleeve-length">
        <line marker-start="url(#arrow)" marker-end="url(#arrow)" x1="85" y1="0" x2="85" y2="120" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
        <text font-size="10" filter="url(#solid)" fill="black" x="85" y="60" class="dimension" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"> 120 cm</text>
    </g>
    <g id="dimension-length">
        <line marker-start="url(#arrow)" marker-end="url(#arrow)" x1="-85" y1="0" x2="-85" y2="154" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
        <text font-size="10" filter="url(#solid)" fill="black" x="-85" y="77" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" class="dimension"> 154 cm</text>
    </g>
    <g id="dimension-sleeve-to-sleeve">
        <line marker-start="url(#arrow)" marker-end="url(#arrow)" x1="-65" y1="-20" x2="65" y2="-20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
        <text font-size="10" filter="url(#solid)" fill="black" x="0" y="-20" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" class="dimension">&nbsp;130 cm&nbsp;</text>
    </g>
    <g title="Back Width" id="dimension-back-width">
        <line marker-start="url(#arrow)" marker-end="url(#arrow)" x1="-30" y1="174" x2="30" y2="174" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></line>
        <text font-size="10" filter="url(#solid)" fill="black" x="0" y="174" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" class="dimension">&nbsp;60 cm&nbsp;</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The use `&nbsp;` instead of `&#160;` causes problems on many browsers as it doesn't validate as SVG.  Also, one might want to add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` as an attribute to the svg tag to ensure the browser interprets this properly (e.g. this doesn't work on Firefox as-is).

Answer (score 0):

An obvious workaround to the problem of the blur produced by the `filter` effect is to render the `<text>` two times: once for the background (with transparent characters) and once for the characters (without a background filter).

For me, this was the only way to make the text readable in Safari.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="solid">
        <feFlood flood-color="yellow" />
    </filter>
    <g transform="translate(20, 50)" font-size="50">
        <text aria-hidden="true" fill="none" filter="url(#solid)">solid background</text>
        <text fill="blue">solid background</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The `aria-hidden="true"` attribute is there to prevent screen readers from speaking the text twice, if the user uses a screen reader.

Answer (score -1):

You can add style to your text:

```
  style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) -2px -2px 0px, rgb(255, 255, 255) -2px 2px 0px, 
     rgb(255, 255, 255) 2px -2px 0px, rgb(255, 255, 255) 2px 2px 0px;"
```

White, in this example.
Does not work in IE :)