# can't change colour of js node text

Tags: javascript, css, colors

Why can't I adjust the css colour of the text in this tree? it allows me to change the text size but I can't seen to change anything like font colour or background colour

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aksb7x06/)

```
.node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `svg` `text` nodes, you'll have to use `fill` instead of `color`:

```css
.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif; 
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="500">
  <g transform="translate(100,20)">
    <g class="node" transform="translate(0,10)">
      <text x="-13" dy=".35em" text-anchor="end" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Product</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aksb7x06/2/)***

Comment: Oh brilliant! I didn't know this. What would be the equivalent of background colour?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no css background attribute for those elements. This question has some alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500894/background-color-of-text-in-svg