# D3 tick with background

Tags: d3.js

How can a D3 axis `tick` have a background color?

A brute way of doing so it to append a `rect` element inside each `g.tick` and have a `fill` on it, but it's quite difficult to achieve, since the `rect` has to be the same size as the text inside the `tick`..

Here's a [basic ticks example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9764126) by Mike Bostock (and [another](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3371592) with graph)

---

I took a screenshot and marked (red border) where I want the ticks to have background color:

[image]

---

Does anyone know of any sane way of having background color on Ticks?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't dismiss your `rect` idea so quickly.  It's pretty simple to implement and allows you to adjust the size of the "background" however you want.  Here's how it would look with your 3 extra pixel:

```
d3.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d,i){
  var tick = d3.select(this),
      text = tick.select('text'),
      bBox = text.node().getBBox();

  tick.insert('rect', ':first-child')
    .attr('x', bBox.x - 3)
    .attr('y', bBox.y - 3)
    .attr('height', bBox.height + 6)
    .attr('width', bBox.width + 6)
    .style('fill', d3.schemeCategory20[i % 20]);      
});
```

---

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain([0, 1, 2])
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1e6, 2e6])
    .range([height, 0]);

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(20, "s"));

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(1) + ",0)")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(20)
        .tickFormat(d3.format(".0s")));

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(2) + ",0)")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(20)
        .tickFormat(d3.formatPrefix(".1", 1e6)));
        
d3.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d,i){
  var tick = d3.select(this),
      text = tick.select('text'),
      bBox = text.node().getBBox();
      
  tick.insert('rect', ':first-child')
    .attr('x', bBox.x - 3)
    .attr('y', bBox.y - 3)
    .attr('height', bBox.height + 6)
    .attr('width', bBox.width + 6)
    .style('fill', d3.schemeCategory20[i % 20]);
  
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! the `getBBox()` was what I needed

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to make a filter like this:

```
  var filter = svg.append("defs").append("filter")
    .attr("x", "0")
    .attr("y", "0")
    .attr("width", "1")
    .attr("height", "1")
    .attr("id", "background")//id of the filter
  filter.append("feFlood")
    .attr("flood-color", "red");
  filter.append("feComposite")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
```

and to ticks add the filter like this:

```
 g.selectAll(".tick text").attr("filter","url(#background)");
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ORCKaXYEbF26APiv1K0Y?p=preview)

Comment: Can this produce custom padding to the background? I was considering filter but it couldn't figure out how to get the padding working. for example have the background be with `3px` padding

Comment: While this works, I have colors as `SCSS` variables and I would prefer to control colors from CSS files and not hard-coded in html/JS

Comment: If you want to style the background with CSS, you can add a class to the feFlood element and then use CSS to set the `flood-color` property for the class.

Answer (score 4):

SVG text background color with padding

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
<defs>
<filter x="-0.5" y="-0.5" width="2" height="2" id="solid">
<feFlood flood-color="#BDBDBD"></feFlood>
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"></feComposite></filter>
</defs>
<text x="50" y="50" font-size="13" fill="#fff" filter="url(#solid)">7%</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to adapt the padding amount a bit? Currently, it shows up as pretty large. The padding is uneven when I change `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`.