# Background color to axis text in D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want to provide background color to y-axis text conditionally in D3, but sadly "fill" attr is not working as it is providing the color to the axis text and not the background to it, It would be a great if i could get a solution to this from SO.

Here is how it look's.

[image]

Here is the chunk of code written conditionally.

**.js**

```
vis.selectAll(".yaxis text")  // select all the text elements for the xaxis
          .style("font-size", "15px")
          .style("font-weight", "bold")
        //   .style("fill","green")
          .style("fill", function(d,i) {
            var str;

            console.log(d);
            if (i == 1) {
            str = 'gray';

            }else if(i == 2){
                str = 'red';

            }else if(i == 3){
                str = 'Blue';

            }
            else if(i == 4){
                str = 'green';

            }

            return str;
            })
```

Comment: I think i answered something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327183/d3-tick-with-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define second parameter in `fill` function:

```
.style("fill", function(d,i) {
```

and then

```
if (i == 1) {
      str = 'gray';

    } ...
```

or compare `d` with text value:

```
if (d == 'Positive') {
      str = 'green';

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bud..! i have changed the code accordingly to your answer but its still not working.!

Comment: But this is what i currently have as shown in the image.! what i want should be something like http://bl.ocks.org/andreaskoller/7674031 but conditionally.!

Comment: Any idea on this.?

Comment: fiddle update: https://jsfiddle.net/tomatetz/p9m9bnv3/2/  you can fill rectangles & add text on top layer

Comment: If not a problem can u please point out in my code what i need to update?

Comment: Any ways bud..u gave me an idea to work out with ticks..! Soo thanks for that.!