# Scale a rectangle in svg to fit the text using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How could I scale a rectangle in `svg` to fit the `text` using d3.js.

When you run it for the first time the `yellowgreen` `rect` covers the text nicely, but if you will resize the screen the text size and position will be changed, while the rectangle stays the same.

Below is the code, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/280/):

```js
    debugger;
var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");

const rectAroundText = svg
  .append("rect");

const textMiddleX = 50;
const textMiddleY = 50;

const testText = svg
  .append("text");
testText
  .attr("x", textMiddleX + "%")
  .attr("y", textMiddleY + "50%")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "central")
  .attr("x", "50%")
  .attr("y", "50%")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .classed("scalingText", true)
  .text("svdfv");
  
  const textBox = testText.node().getBBox();
  
  rectAroundText
 .attr("x", textBox.x)
  .attr("y", textBox.y)
  .attr("width", textBox.width)
  .attr("height", textBox.height)
  .attr("fill", "yellowgreen");
```

```html
    <div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I would like the rectangle to scale up and move along with the text. Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500894/background-color-of-text-in-svg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background color of text in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500894/background-color-of-text-in-svg)