# Adjust SVG rect width according to its content

Tags: css, svg

I'm creating an SVG with a few rects **dynamically** .

Inside of a rect there's a text which its width can change.

I want the width of the rect to adjust according to the length of the text.

I s it possible or what are the workarounds?

Here's a fiddle with a simple example:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wo5qfrce/2/)

Here's the SVG:

```html
  <div class="container">
   <svg height="180" width="500">
      <g transform="translate(100, 50)">
         <rect width="100%" class="node" rx="17" height="30" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: default;"></rect>
         <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15" fill="#FFFFFF" filter="url(#circleShadow)" stroke="lightgray" stroke-width="0.1" width="15" height="15"></circle>
         <text x="40" y="19" class="graph-element-text node-text-color" style="cursor: pointer;">long text11111111111111122222</text>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013492/1038015) perhaps?

Comment: @RobertLongson - I'm not sure how's that related to my situation.
I'm building an SVG dynamically in code and the text child element width can change and I need the rect to display all the text.

Comment: And why do you think that's not related to your situation?

Comment: @RobertLongson - my bad - I missed that part.
The foreignObject  solution worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Robert Longson implied: you have to mimic a `<div>` like display of text boxes in svg, since `<text>` elements don't have any auto-growing capabilities. (at least not comparable to html block elements).

Actually, there a `<rects>` can't wrap a text element (like e.g. a div)

A workaround might be using a [foreign object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject):

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
}


.graph-background-color {
    background-color: #F8F8F9;
}

svg {
  fill: yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}


.text-wrp{
    text-align:center;
}
.inner-text{
  text-align:center;
  background:#fff;
  width:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2em;
  height:30px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:1.75em;
  border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em
}
```

```html
<div >
  <svg class="container" height="180" width="500">
    <g>
      <foreignObject x="50%" y="50%" width="50%" height="50" style="transform:translateX(-25%) translateY(-15%)">
        <div class="text-wrp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <div class="inner-text" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            long text11111111111111122222</div>
          </div>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

`<foreignObject>` might introduce issues, when your svg needs to be standalon (e.g. should also be editable in an editor like Ai, inkscape).