Javascript scroll bars on Legends that are too large
// The MIT License (MIT)

// Copyright (c) 2017 Zalando SE

// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.


function radar_visualization(config) {

  // custom random number generator, to make random sequence reproducible
  // source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295
  var seed = 42;
  function random() {
    var x = Math.sin(seed++) * 10000;
    return x - Math.floor(x);
  }

  function random_between(min, max) {
    return min + random() * (max - min);
  }

  function normal_between(min, max) {
    return min + (random() + random()) * 0.5 * (max - min);
  }

  // radial_min / radial_max are multiples of PI
    const quadrants = [
    { radial_min: 0, radial_max: 0.5, factor_x: 1, factor_y: 1 },
    { radial_min: 0.5, radial_max: 1, factor_x: -1, factor_y: 1 },
    { radial_min: -1, radial_max: -0.5, factor_x: -1, factor_y: -1 },
    { radial_min: -0.5, radial_max: 0, factor_x: 1, factor_y: -1 }
  ];

  const rings = [
    { radius: 130 },
    { radius: 220 },
    { radius: 310 },
    { radius: 400 }
  ];

  const title_offset =
    { x: -675, y: -420 };

  const footer_offset =
    { x: -675, y: 420 };

  const legend_offset = [
    { x: 450, y: 90 },
    { x: -675, y: 90 },
    { x: -675, y: -310 },
    { x: 450, y: -310 }
  ];

  function polar(cartesian) {
    var x = cartesian.x;
    var y = cartesian.y;
    return {
      t: Math.atan2(y, x),
      r: Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
    }
  }

  function cartesian(polar) {
    return {
      x: polar.r * Math.cos(polar.t),
      y: polar.r * Math.sin(polar.t)
    }
  }

  function bounded_interval(value, min, max) {
    var low = Math.min(min, max);
    var high = Math.max(min, max);
    return Math.min(Math.max(value, low), high);
  }

  function bounded_ring(polar, r_min, r_max) {
    return {
      t: polar.t,
      r: bounded_interval(polar.r, r_min, r_max)
    }
  }

  function bounded_box(point, min, max) {
    return {
      x: bounded_interval(point.x, min.x, max.x),
      y: bounded_interval(point.y, min.y, max.y)
    }
  }

  function segment(quadrant, ring) {
    var polar_min = {
      t: quadrants[quadrant].radial_min * Math.PI,
      r: ring === 0 ? 30 : rings[ring - 1].radius
    };
    var polar_max = {
      t: quadrants[quadrant].radial_max * Math.PI,
      r: rings[ring].radius
    };
    var cartesian_min = {
      x: 15 * quadrants[quadrant].factor_x,
      y: 15 * quadrants[quadrant].factor_y
    };
    var cartesian_max = {
      x: rings[3].radius * quadrants[quadrant].factor_x,
      y: rings[3].radius * quadrants[quadrant].factor_y
    };
    return {
      clipx: function(d) {
        var c = bounded_box(d, cartesian_min, cartesian_max);
        var p = bounded_ring(polar(c), polar_min.r + 15, polar_max.r - 15);
        d.x = cartesian(p).x; // adjust data too!
        return d.x;
      },
      clipy: function(d) {
        var c = bounded_box(d, cartesian_min, cartesian_max);
        var p = bounded_ring(polar(c), polar_min.r + 15, polar_max.r - 15);
        d.y = cartesian(p).y; // adjust data too!
        return d.y;
      },
      random: function() {
        return cartesian({
          t: random_between(polar_min.t, polar_max.t),
          r: normal_between(polar_min.r, polar_max.r)
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // position each entry randomly in its segment
  for (var i = 0; i < config.entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = config.entries[i];
    entry.segment = segment(entry.quadrant, entry.ring);
    var point = entry.segment.random();
    entry.x = point.x;
    entry.y = point.y;
    entry.color = entry.active || config.print_layout ?
      config.rings[entry.ring].color : config.colors.inactive;
  }

  // partition entries according to segments
  var segmented = new Array(4);
  for (var quadrant = 0; quadrant < 4; quadrant++) {
    segmented[quadrant] = new Array(4);
    for (var ring = 0; ring < 4; ring++) {
      segmented[quadrant][ring] = [];
    }
  }
  for (var i=0; i<config.entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = config.entries[i];
    segmented[entry.quadrant][entry.ring].push(entry);
  }

  // assign unique sequential id to each entry
  var id = 1;
  for (var quadrant of [2,3,1,0]) {
    for (var ring = 0; ring < 4; ring++) {
      var entries = segmented[quadrant][ring];
      entries.sort(function(a,b) { return a.label.localeCompare(b.label); })
      for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        entries[i].id = "" + id++;
      }
    }
  }

  function translate(x, y) {
    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  }

  function viewbox(quadrant) {
    return [
      Math.max(0, quadrants[quadrant].factor_x * 400) - 420,
      Math.max(0, quadrants[quadrant].factor_y * 400) - 420,
      440,
      440
    ].join(" ");
  }

  var svg = d3.select("svg#" + config.svg_id)
    .style("background-color", config.colors.background)
    .attr("width", config.width)
    .attr("height", config.height);

  var radar = svg.append("g");
  if ("zoomed_quadrant" in config) {
    svg.attr("viewBox", viewbox(config.zoomed_quadrant));
  } else {
    radar.attr("transform", translate(config.width / 2, config.height / 2));
  }

  var grid = radar.append("g");

  // draw grid lines
  grid.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", -400)
    .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", 400)
    .style("stroke", config.colors.grid)
    .style("stroke-width", 1);
  grid.append("line")
    .attr("x1", -400).attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 400).attr("y2", 0)
    .style("stroke", config.colors.grid)
    .style("stroke-width", 1);

  // background color. Usage `.attr("filter", "url(#solid)")`
  // SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013492/2609980
  var defs = grid.append("defs");
  var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    .attr("id", "solid");
  filter.append("feFlood")
    .attr("flood-color", "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8)");
  filter.append("feComposite")
    .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

  // draw rings
  for (var i = 0; i < rings.length; i++) {
    grid.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 0)
      .attr("cy", 0)
      .attr("r", rings[i].radius)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", config.colors.grid)
      .style("stroke-width", 1);
    if (config.print_layout) {
      grid.append("text")
        .text(config.rings[i].name)
        .attr("y", -rings[i].radius + 62)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("fill", config.rings[i].color)
        .style("opacity", 0.35)
        .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
        .style("font-size", "42px")
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .style("user-select", "none");
    }
  }

  function legend_transform(quadrant, ring, index=null) {
    var dx = ring < 2 ? 0 : 140;
    var dy = (index == null ? -16 : index * 12);
    if (ring % 2 === 1) {
      dy = dy + 36 + segmented[quadrant][ring-1].length * 12;
    }
    return translate(
      legend_offset[quadrant].x + dx,
      legend_offset[quadrant].y + dy
    );
  }

  // draw title and legend (only in print layout)
  if (config.print_layout) {

    // title
    radar.append("text")
      .attr("transform", translate(title_offset.x, title_offset.y))
      .text(config.title)
      .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
      .style("font-size", "30")
      .style("font-weight", "bold")

    // date
    radar
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", translate(title_offset.x, title_offset.y + 20))
      .text(config.date || "")
      .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
      .style("font-size", "14")
      .style("fill", "#999")

    // legend
    var legend = radar.append("g");
    for (var quadrant = 0; quadrant < 4; quadrant++) {
      legend.append("text")
        .attr("transform", translate(
          legend_offset[quadrant].x,
          legend_offset[quadrant].y - 45
        ))
        .text(config.quadrants[quadrant].name)
        .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
        .style("font-size", "18px")
        .style("font-weight", "bold");
      for (var ring = 0; ring < 4; ring++) {
        legend.append("text")
          .attr("transform", legend_transform(quadrant, ring))
          .text(config.rings[ring].name)
          .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
          .style("font-size", "12px")
          .style("font-weight", "bold")
          .style("fill", config.rings[ring].color);
        legend.selectAll(".legend" + quadrant + ring)
          .data(segmented[quadrant][ring])
          .enter()
            .append("a")
              .attr("href", function (d, i) {
                 return d.link ? d.link : "#"; // stay on same page if no link was provided
              })
              // Add a target if (and only if) there is a link and we want new tabs
              .attr("target", function (d, i) {
                 return (d.link && config.links_in_new_tabs) ? "_blank" : null;
              })
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return legend_transform(quadrant, ring, i); })
              .attr("class", "legend" + quadrant + ring)
              .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "legendItem" + d.id; })
              .text(function(d, i) { return d.id + ". " + d.label; })
              .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
              .style("font-size", "11px")
              .on("mouseover", function(d) { showBubble(d); highlightLegendItem(d); })
              .on("mouseout", function(d) { hideBubble(d); unhighlightLegendItem(d); });
      }
    }
  }

  // layer for entries
  var rink = radar.append("g")
    .attr("id", "rink");

  // rollover bubble (on top of everything else)
  var bubble = radar.append("g")
    .attr("id", "bubble")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .style("user-select", "none");
  bubble.append("rect")
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .style("fill", "#333");
  bubble.append("text")
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .style("font-size", "10px")
    .style("fill", "#fff");
  bubble.append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0,0 10,0 5,8 z")
    .style("fill", "#333");

  function showBubble(d) {
    if (d.active || config.print_layout) {
      var tooltip = d3.select("#bubble text")
        .text(d.label);
      var bbox = tooltip.node().getBBox();
      d3.select("#bubble")
        .attr("transform", translate(d.x - bbox.width / 2, d.y - 16))
        .style("opacity", 0.8);
      d3.select("#bubble rect")
        .attr("x", -5)
        .attr("y", -bbox.height)
        .attr("width", bbox.width + 10)
        .attr("height", bbox.height + 4);
      d3.select("#bubble path")
        .attr("transform", translate(bbox.width / 2 - 5, 3));
    }
  }

  function hideBubble(d) {
    var bubble = d3.select("#bubble")
      .attr("transform", translate(0,0))
      .style("opacity", 0);
  }

  function highlightLegendItem(d) {
    var legendItem = document.getElementById("legendItem" + d.id);
    legendItem.setAttribute("filter", "url(#solid)");
    legendItem.setAttribute("fill", "white");
  }

  function unhighlightLegendItem(d) {
    var legendItem = document.getElementById("legendItem" + d.id);
    legendItem.removeAttribute("filter");
    legendItem.removeAttribute("fill");
  }

  // draw blips on radar
  var blips = rink.selectAll(".blip")
    .data(config.entries)
    .enter()
      .append("g")
        .attr("class", "blip")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return legend_transform(d.quadrant, d.ring, i); })
        .on("mouseover", function(d) { showBubble(d); highlightLegendItem(d); })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) { hideBubble(d); unhighlightLegendItem(d); });

  // configure each blip
  blips.each(function(d) {
    var blip = d3.select(this);

    // blip link
    if (d.active && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(d, "link") && d.link) {
      blip = blip.append("a")
        .attr("xlink:href", d.link);

      if (config.links_in_new_tabs) {
        blip.attr("target", "_blank");
      }
    }

    // blip shape
    if (d.moved > 0) {
      blip.append("path")
        .attr("d", "M -11,5 11,5 0,-13 z") // triangle pointing up
        .style("fill", d.color);
    } else if (d.moved < 0) {
      blip.append("path")
        .attr("d", "M -11,-5 11,-5 0,13 z") // triangle pointing down
        .style("fill", d.color);
    } else {
      blip.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 9)
        .attr("fill", d.color);
    }

    // blip text
    if (d.active || config.print_layout) {
      var blip_text = config.print_layout ? d.id : d.label.match(/[a-z]/i);
      blip.append("text")
        .text(blip_text)
        .attr("y", 3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("fill", "#fff")
        .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return blip_text.length > 2 ? "8px" : "9px"; })
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .style("user-select", "none");
    }
  });

  // make sure that blips stay inside their segment
  function ticked() {
    blips.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return translate(d.segment.clipx(d), d.segment.clipy(d));
    })
  }

  // distribute blips, while avoiding collisions
  d3.forceSimulation()
    .nodes(config.entries)
    .velocityDecay(0.19) // magic number (found by experimentation)
    .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(12).strength(0.85))
    .on("tick", ticked);
}


So i'm using the basic opensource Zalando radar to display data. I have python knowledge so i have made changes to the python side of the code to make the radar accept my data format.
Where i'm struggling is the JavaScript. I have no JS knowledge so have only been following other guides / fixes but to no avail.
What i'm trying to do is stop the legends from expanding into one another (each quadrant has a legend showing each data point in the quadrant) some of my quadrants are quite expansive in data thus the legend ends up being too long and overlapping the legend below.
I was hoping i could limit the size of the legend and then add some scroll bars to those that exceed the given size.
for (var ring = 0; ring < 4; ring++) {
    legend.append("text")
        .attr("transform", legend_transform(quadrant, ring))
        .text(function(d, i) {
            return d.label; // Retain original label
        })
        .style("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica")
        .style("font-size", "12px")
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        .style("fill", config.rings[ring].color)
        .style("max-height", "50px") // Adjust max-height as needed
        .style("overflow", "hidden")
        .style("text-overflow", "ellipsis")
        .style("line-height", "1em");

I have tried just limiting the size of the legend but that has not been successful
my attempts have either led to no change in the display, or the whole thing falling over dramatically and no information being displayed at all
