# Highcharts Styling Questions

Tags: highcharts

I'm hoping for some help on styling a line Highchart.

I'm trying to get the graph here to look like the image:

[Example of my graph](http://www.myhealthcoach.tv/HRA/aardvark.php)

But I'm struggling to get the block colour lables?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            plotBackgroundImage: 'images/fibre.jpg',
            plotBorderWidth: 0,


            /*,
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25*/
        },
        title: 
        {
            text    : strTitle
        },
        tooltip: 
        {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: 
        {
            categories: arrXAxis,               
            title: 
            {
                text: strXTitle
            },

        },          
        yAxis: 
        {
            title: 
            {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                   // return this.value +'?'
                   return('');
                }
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            alternateGridColor: null,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            plotBands: 
            [{ 
                from: intRedStart,
                to: intRedEnd,
                color: 'rgba(229, 28, 36, 0.6)',
                label: 
                {
                    text: 'High Risk',
                    style: 
                    {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            },
            { 
                from: intAmberStart,
                to: intAmberEnd,
                color: 'rgba(239, 140, 30, 0.6)',
                label: 
                {
                    text: 'Improvement',
                    style: 
                    {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            },
            { 
                from: intGreenStart,
                to: intGreenEnd,
                color: 'rgba(43, 174, 115, 0.6)',
                label: 
                {
                    text: 'Healthy',
                    style: 
                    {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }   


            ]
        },
        legend: {
           /*
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0*/
        },
        series:
        [{
            allowPointSelect: false,    
            showInLegend: false,
            data: arrData   
        }   /*, {
                name: '1',
                data: [10]
            }, {
                name: '2',
                data: [0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: '3',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }*/]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [API doc for plotband labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands.label), I think you should be able to do something similar to the image by playing around with the "style", "align" and "verticalAlign" properties. Hope this helps :)

Edit: It seems like the background color is not possible to set with the labels.style object. I guess this is because the label is an SVG element (a tspan to be more specific), so it does not support all the css that standard HTML elements does. You can however come closer to your goal by aligning the labels "top" and "left", and set the font color. If you really need the background color you may have a look at this: [Background color of tspan element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675223/background-color-of-tspan-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can set plotBackgroundImage for chart http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.plotBackgroundImage and then use plotBands 
http://jsfiddle.net/JRhaS/2/

```
 plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'rgba(155,255,155,0.5)',
            from: 0,
            to: 100
        },{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'rgba(100,255,200,0.5)',
            from:100,
            to: 200
        }],
    },
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but it's the blocks of solid colour with the words Healthy, Improvement, High Risk I'm trying to recreate - not the opaque plotbands over the image!

Comment: Have yuu tried to set plotbands labels ? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands.label ?

Comment: The labels work, but setting a background-color style doesn't seem to work. This is also the case with chart labels. I can't find a way to do what TheBounder wants. I've updated his post to include chart source from his link.

Comment: @SteveP backgroundcolor for labels or plotband? Im not sure?

Comment: setting background color in the style for a label doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. I tried to explain this about the background color not being configurable, and one possible workaround by manually drawing an SVG rect behind the label.